# Unable to change the look of contact form 7 in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a wordpress landing page, and I use Contact Form 7 to collect my leads. The thing is that I'm unable to design the "Thank you message" with CSS. I wish to align the text to the center and change the border from green to orange. I used the following CSS:

```
div.wpcf7-response-output {
    padding: 0.2em 1em;
}

div.wpcf7-mail-sent-ok {
    border: 2px solid #ff6600;
  text-align: center;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

The CSS is not working, I also tried to use !important. You can see the form I'm trying to design at the bottom of the page- http://mickeyberkowitz.com/

The form's shortcode is:

```
<center> 

</label> <label for= ".wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-text.wpcf7-tel.wpcf7-validates-as-required.wpcf7-validates-as-tel* your-email"> <input type="tel" textarea name="your-phone" input placeholder="טלפון" id:phone required</input></label><label for=".elementor-6 .elementor-element.elementor-element-5m0lukt .wpcf7 input[type="text"]"><input type=text textarea name="your-name" placeholder="שם מלא" required id:name </input>

[submit "!אני רוצה עוד פרטים"]
</center>
```

Comment: where did you put that css?

Comment: The CSS classes are being placed in the `for` attribute and not in the `class` attribute so they wouldn't get applied.

Comment: @hungerstar it renders as `<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ok" role="alert" style="display: block;">!הודעתכם נקלטה, ניצור עמכם קשר בהקדם</div>`

Comment: If that's the case I think I'd drop that plugin asap. I'd have trouble trusting such hackery.